I'm a bit [salt]y about these tags
The tag salt is supposed to refer to the cryptography concept:

Cryptography function that takes random bits and a string (typically a password) and uses a one-way hash to provide a new string that can be used for authentication without providing access to the original string. If a salt function uses enough random bits, the resulting string is generally considered cryptographically secure.

However, it is being used to mean salt-stack (examples: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8):

The Salt Project, previously known as SaltStack, is a Python-based open-source configuration management software and remote execution engine.

That description suggests that this tag name is outdated.
There are also these tags:

saltedhash (70 questions; seems like a synonym of salt
salt-creation (8 questions; seems to be effectively being used as a synonym of salt, except for one question in which it seems to refer to salt-stack)

What should be done about these?

Take these tags with a pinch of [salt].

"I'm all out of [salt], I'm not gonna cry" has been stuck in my head thanks to having written this.

This has reached +18/-0 pretty quickly, so I'm calling that a consensus (it was +16 when I started doing it, but it took a bit).  It is now done.
I ended up rewriting the excerpt for salt-cryptography entirely, because it was confusing and arguably not entirely accurate.  It now reads:

A salt, in cryptography, is additional random data (stored in the database alongside the resulting hash) added to the input of a one-way hash function (typically a password) that differs between entries. It defends against password-hash cracking by preventing the use of rainbow tables and requiring each password to be cracked separately. For the Salt Project IT-infrastructure administration/automation tool, use [salt-project] instead.

Additionally, I retagged two additional salt-creation questions that were actually about salt-project.
There are probably more mistagged salt-project questions under salt-cryptography; I only skimmed the first couple pages and searched for questions with both tags.  Please feel free to retag any others you see.

My proposal is:

Rename salt to salt-cryptography

Without a synonym, because it's a prefix and it'll show up when you type it. There are only 8 tags that contain "salt" (two of which are "universal-" followed by a word starting with "t").  This is one of the two most popular, by an order of magnitude.


Merge saltedhash into salt-cryptography (currently salt)

Create a synonym for salted-hash, because this tag name should have a dash in it (it's two words).


Merge salt-creation into salt-cryptography (currently salt)

Without a synonym, because this seems pointless as a tag; it's getting almost no use.


Rename salt-stack to salt-project

With a synonym, because this is the project's former name and people may know it by this name.


Add a note to the tag excerpt for salt-cryptography (currently salt) pointing users to salt-project (currently salt-stack)
Retag the questions that I identified in this question as incorrectly tagged


If there's anything I missed, or you have ideas for better naming, please leave a comment with suggestions.

I'd say go ahead and do it. It's the most obvious solution.

Looks perfect to me.
